# Objective - C Connection Test Warnings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, connection, warnings

I have the following code:

```
    //View guest list
-(IBAction) guestList:(id) sender{
    NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"myURL"]];

    //Waits a set peroid of time
    wait(20000);

    //Guest list is availible
    if (connected != NULL){
        CHARLIEAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate displayView:6];
    }
    //No network connection availible
    else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Network Connection!" message:@"Cannot establish internet connection."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    }

 }
```

And I get the following warnings:

```
//Waits a set peroid of time
    wait(20000);
```

Gives me -
warning: passing argument 1 of 'wait' makes pointer from integer without a cast

```
NSString *connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/testconnection.php"]];
```

Gives me -

> warning: 'stringWithContentsOfURL:' is deprecated (declared at /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.3.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Headers/NSString.h:384)

I've done my testing and the code SEEMS to work fine, even though there are these warnings.  Is there a way to remove these warnings at all?  Or do they not matter?

I'm using xCode version 3.2.6

Thanks,

Jack

Comment: Don't use `wait()` or `sleep()` or friends.  That blocks the main thread for no reason.  Just use the built in connection methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
NSError* error;  
NSString* connected = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the method -

```
+(id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

for example -

```
NSString* text = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:TheUrl encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
-(IBAction)guestList:(id) sender{
    NSURL *requestUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://photostiubhart.comoj.com/testconnection.php"];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:requestUrl];
    NSData *loadTest   = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:requestUrl];

    if (loadTest == nil) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Network Connection!" message:@"Cannot establish internet connection."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
    } else {
        CHARLIEAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [appDelegate displayView:6];
    }
}
```